# should I manually create .vim/bundle directory for Vundle?

Tags: vim, vundle

I am trying to get started working with vim and I wanted to install Vundle because I've heard it's a good plugin to have and I like being able to customize my text editors.  The instructions on gmarik's git page say to clone the project into ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim, but that's not working because my .vim isn't stored in my home directory, and I don't have a /bundle/ directory in the .vim directory. I figure that I can just change the path to where my .vim directory is, but what I'm not sure about is if I'm supposed to have bundle installed (I saw that Vundle is built on bundle) or if I can just create the /bundle/directory manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your `.vim` at its normal location:

   ```
   ~/.vim
   ```
2. Create the `bundle` directory:

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/.vim/bundle
   ```

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure where to put my .vim directory, either, so I just stuck it somewhere. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: and just to check, my .vimrc file should be in my home directory, too, right?

Comment: You can put the vimrc either in your home directory, with an initial period (i.e. `.vimrc`); or, if you have a recent Vim, in the .vim directory, without the period (i.e. `~/.vim/vimrc`).